# Docker container restart priority

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a bunch of docker containers running in swarm mode (services). If the whole server restarts then containers start to run one by one after server reboot. Is there a way to set an order of container creation and run?

P.S. I can't user docker-compose as these services were created dynamically through Docker Remote API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a shorter restart delay (with `--restart-delay`) to the services you want to start firstly and a bigger to next one etc..

**But I am not sure that working.**